# Manipulate bitmap for best ocr detection

Tags: android, bitmap, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract ORC library to extract text from images taken on screens. Problem is that most modern cameras also captures the pixel on a display while taking a photo.

Is there anyway to apply like a filter or threasholding to the bitmap to "extract" the text to a clearer one for better results with tesseract?

Se example, before processing:
[image]

After processing (threshold effect in photoshop):
[image]

Comment: Hello Richard can you give me your code i also fetch this problem to read character from Image but i can`t success much as you so i can use your code and try to solve my error.

Comment: Zala, read http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ and follow the instructions :)

Comment: i also try this code but can`t success please give me your code dear sir

Comment: i need this code now i am stuck without your help sir please share your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract has a built-in threshold method, `TessBaseAPI#ThresholdRect`. Have you tried that? If so, what problems did you have with it?

If it didn't work so well on some pictures, you may want to try looking up some "mean" or "adaptive" threshold algorithms, since it looks like Tesseract's is a straight threshold, so it may not adapt well to darker/lighter images without some tweaking.

Comment: i am using TessBaseApi, and i don't see this method you speak of..  can you show us an example of how you are implementing it?  I too am trying to force a bitmap to a strict two color threshold black and white.. im so lost